# React + Electron: Dynamically load user-provided fonts?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm making an Electron + React app, where the user should be able to provide his own fonts. Basically the user would put the fonts he wants to use in a folder next to the executable, and then the executable will read the folder and make those fonts useable.

Is this possible to do? All I could find was has to define custom fonts when I already know of their existence beforehand. But I don't.

So if this is possible, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly with the font loading API. https://medium.com/@matuzo/getting-started-with-css-font-loading-e24e7ffaa791

Comment: @AKX I'm checking it out, and will report back. Thanks!

Comment: @AKX It works! Usin `new FontFace(name, path)`, and then push it with `document.fonts.add(font);` I am able to use them with the name! Seems the named can't have spaces or dots, but other than that it works flawlessly. If you add that as an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Done deal! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answerify my comment, you can use the [CSS Font Loading API (link to tutorial)](https://medium.com/@matuzo/getting-started-with-css-font-loading-e24e7ffaa791), i.e.

```
const fontFace = new FontFace("SomeName", "LocalPath.woff2");
document.fonts.add(fontFace);
```